# SSRS - Backup Encryption Key from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssrs

I have a SQL Server with SSRS installed.
Note that SQL runs as NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
SSRS runs as NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices
Version: SQL Server 2017

I am trying to automate the backing up of the encryption.
I have a batch file called rskey.bat that contains the following:

[image]

There is a file called "answer.yes" which contains only a "Y" as input for the **"Are you sure you want to extract the key from the report server? Yes (Y)/ No (N): "** question.

When I try and execute this batch file from SSMS with this:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\Backups\rskey.bat'
```

I get this error:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

When I run the batch file manually, it works.
I just cannot get it to work through SSMS even when running SSMS as administrator

I have made **NT Service\MSSQLSERVER** & **NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices** admin on the server already and has necessary permissions on the folder.

For some context:
I want this to work so that I can schedule the encryption key backups. I have this exact method running on all other SSRS servers without any issue.
The only difference is that all other SSRS servers run the services as a domain account and not the virtual account NT Service\MSSQLSERVER

Could this be the reason?
How can I get this to work without having the services running as a domain account?

Any ideas?

I ran Process Monitor and dug this out:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: "I have made NT Service\MSSQLSERVER & NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices admin on the server" bad idea and not necessary. Why are you trying to run this batch file from SSMS anyway, why not run it from Scheduled Tasks or something? I'd assume the actual issue is that MSSQLSERVER has no permissions on the keys belonging to SQLServerReportingServices, which is another reason to run it from Scheduled Tasks.

Comment: I tested it with Task Scheduler and that works 100%. I set it to run as Builtin\Administrators. 
This helps confirm that it is a permission issue for the NT Service\MSSQLSERVER account

Answer (score 0):

> The only difference is that all other SSRS servers run the services as a domain account and not the virtual account NT Service\MSSQLSERVER

I know virtual account provisioning can get a little *weird* sometimes. Admittedly, I'm also not very knowledgeable on the administrative side of Windows security.

But I'm curious if provisioning the appropriate permissions to the folder for the domain account that represents the machine itself (sorry I can't recall the name of this type of account) might work here. I.e. if the machine is called `MySqlServerPC` then I believe there should be an account called `TheDomainThatPCIsJoinedTo\MySqlServerPC$` (or it may be `TheDomainThatPCIsJoinedTo\$MySqlServerPC` - I can't recall the proper format).

Again, bit of a stretch here, with my super limited knowledge, but let me know if that helps.

---

The other thing worth checking, and honestly may more likely be your issue here, is the [proxy account that your `xp_cmdshell` runs under](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#xp_cmdshell-proxy-account). This can be a Windows account that differs from the virtual account your SQL Server service runs under, and may be where your issue lies with provisioning folder security.

Comment: I added domain\computername$ as admin on the server and still does not work. 

Also, I checked and xp_cmdshell does not run under a proxy - Nothing returned by SELECT * FROM sys.credentials WHERE name = '##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##'